# Can't POST json data with curl in windows

Tags: json, curl

I have read several posts about this topic but i couldn't figure out how to send json data with curl POST on windows 10 (powershell).

I tried with \" or with """ nothing.
json data:

```
{
    "frames": [
        {
            "text": "HOME2",
            "icon": "i294",
            "index": 0
        },
        {
            "text": "? 65",
            "icon": null,
            "index": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Example of curl tries:

```
> curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Access-Token: xyz" -X POST "https://xyz" -d "{ """frames""": [{ """text""": """HOME2""", """icon""": """i294""", """index""": 0 }, { """text""": """? 65""", """icon""": null, """index""": 1 }]}"
{"error":{"code":null,"message":"Bad Request","trace":["request body must not be empty"]}}curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: text
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: HOME2,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: icon
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: i294,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: index
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 0
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: text
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ? 65,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: icon
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: null,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: index
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
```

with \"

```
> curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Access-Token: xyz" -X POST "https://xyz" -d "{ \"frames\": [ { \"text\": \"HOME2\", \"icon\": \"i294\", \"index\": 0 }, { \"text\": \"? 65\", \"icon\": null, \"index\": 1 } ] }"
{"error":{"code":null,"message":"Bad Request","trace":["request body must not be empty"]}}curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 2
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \text\
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \HOME2\,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \icon\
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \i294\,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \index\
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 0
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \text\
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \? 65\,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \icon\
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: null,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \index\
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after further reading and from the answer from mohsen, I finalized my command line to:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Access-Token: xyz" -X POST "https://xyz" -d @exported.json
```

I added the json into a file called exported.json and now it is more compact and it still works.

The json data it self didn't need much more tweaking, see exported.json file:

```
{"frames":[{"text":"HOME2","icon":"i294","index":"0"},{"text":"? 65","icon":"null","index":"1"}]}
```

Comment: On windows cmd prompt, curl really wants the @ before the path to the file.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Windows command line and PowerShell messes with curl and JSON post data. Tried the following in CMD, PowerShell and WSL. WSL gives the result I expected, the other two fails. (originally tried to post data to Node-Red, and their official example failed, that was my WTF moment)

Try this (httpbin.org just echoes your data back this case):

`curl -X POST -d '{"name":"Nick","a":32}' -H "Content-type:application/json" https://httpbin.org/anything`

Response when called from WSL:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{\"name\":\"Nick\",\"a\":32}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Length": "22",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.71.1"
  },
  "json": {
    "a": 32,
    "name": "Nick"
  },
  "method": "POST",
  "origin": "*********",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything"
}
```

Response when called from CMD / PS:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "'{name:Nick,a:32}'",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Length": "18",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.55.1"
  },
  "json": null,
  "method": "POST",
  "origin": "****",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything"
}
```

Notice `Content-Length` is different and the `json` property in the response is `null` when called from cmd or ps.

But doing this does work from both WSL and cmd, but not from PowerShell:  `curl -d "{\"name\":\"Nick\",\"a\":32}" -H "Content-type:application/json" https://httpbin.org/anything`

And this works in PowerShell but fails in the other two `curl -d '{\"name\":\"Nick\",\"a\":32}' -H "Content-type:application/json" https://httpbin.org/anything`

So yes, put your post data in a file. But of course, powershell has it's own rules, so in the others you can do `-d @data.json`, but in powershell you must fo `` -d `@data.json `` (backtick before the `@` symbol)

Answer (score 1):

> first minify your json [here](https://www.cleancss.com/json-minify/), don't use pretty json.

try this:

```
curl -d 'curl -d '{"frames":[{"text":"HOME2","icon":"i294","index":0}, 
 {"text":"? 65","icon":null,"index":1}]}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
 https://example.com/login
```

for more info check this [site](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-perform-a-post-request-using-curl)

Comment: This helped but only cygwin windows. On windows powershell it still raises the error.

Comment: Your example yes, but if i use my json data set it still complains in windows powershell.

Comment: I updated my question with my latest findings and what works now.

Comment: don't update question just answer your question to make community better

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would share my findings on this in case it helps others.

For me, to get this to work, I simply had to toggle the single and double quotes, ironically, making the JSON not correctly formatted:

**DOES NOT WORK:**

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"text":"Hello World"}' https://my-unique-slack-hooks-url-here.com
```

**DOES WORK:**

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d "{'text':'Hello, World'}" https://my-unique-slack-hooks-url-here.com
```